# $state.go(" Any url and not just a State ")

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to write something like `$state.go("/spheres/{{$stateParams.sphereId}}/mono/view");` with an outside url and not a state but this does not work :(

Now I get why this doesnt work because $state requires a state, but is there a work around?

The reason I want to use this and not:

```
window.location.replace("/spheres" + $stateParams.sphereId + "/mono/view");
window.location.href = "/spheres/" + $stateParams.sphereId + "/mono/view";
```

is because I have a soundbite that is played upon linking to the next URL and for some reason, `location` & `href` halts that soundbite upon linking.

Ironically using href in an `<a>` tag does work without deactivating the soundbite, but then I run into another issue where href/ng-href cannot be called with ng-click on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've defined the state URL with a parameter called sphereId:

```
state: 'spheres.details.mono.view',
url: '/spheres/:sphereId/mono/view'
```

You can go to the parameterized state by:

```
$state.go('spheres.details.mono.view', { sphereId: $stateParams.sphereId });
```

Comment: This is a great solution, however the only way to access `mono` is to link it as a string URL. `mono` has no state :( This because there is both `mono` and `stereo`. How can i link using the string `"/spheres" + $stateParams.sphereId + "/mono/view"`

Comment: I do want to clarify that if the only param i needed was `sphereId`, this solution would get the Green Check :)

Comment: Can't you make mono/stereo another parameter called `viewType` etc.?

Comment: It would be nice to give in to making everything state/stateParam based as opposed to a hybrid approach.